# Teria "uai" alguma relação com o inglês "why"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões, origem-histórica, estrangeirismos, interjeições

No português, há a interjeição ["uai"](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=uai) que pode ser usado para demonstrar um espanto ou surpresa. No inglês, a palavra "why", além de um advérbio, também pode ser uma interjeição, curiosamente também usada para demonstrar um espanto ou surpresa.

Segundo o [dicionário](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/why), o uso de *why* como interjeição é antigo (fora de moda), e realmente, quando eu vi esse termo pela primeira vez, eu estava jogando um jogo (RPG) de 1998 (que inclusive usava incessantemente essa expressão) e outro de 1995.

Mas teria o nosso uai alguma relação com o do inglês?

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser [discutida no meta](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/276/153)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Custa-me a acreditar que alguém escreveu uma tese sobre a palavra uai, [mas ela existe](http://hdl.handle.net/1843/BUOS-9BVJCP).

> Dentre as hipóteses discutidas, descartamos algumas e outras ficam em
> aberto. Dentre estas últimas, a hipótese do empréstimo britânico
> parece plausível. Entretanto, quando comparadas à de Amaral, discutida
> no capítulo III, aquela parece ter consequências gramaticais mais
> interessantes. Por isso, optamos por inseri-la em nossa origem. Mesmo
> assim, a questão sobre a origem de ‘uai’ continua em aberto. Novas
> pesquisas poderão mostrar se nossa opção foi a mais adequada.
>
> ...
>
> Amaral ([1920] 1976:190), no famoso livro ‘O Dialeto Caipira’,
> registrou a ocorrência desse item no falar de roceiros paulistas no
> noroeste do Estado de São Paulo e afirma haver existido no falar dessa
> comunidade as formas ‘olhai’, ‘oiai’, ‘uiai’, ‘uai’, ‘uéi~ué’ e
> ‘uêi~uê’, todas desempenhando a mesma função comunicativa (assinalar
> ‘surpresa’ ou ‘espanto’), ou seja, seriam formas variantes. Essa
> descoberta levou o autor a propor que o item ‘uai’ é um brasileirismo
> e teria surgido no dialeto paulista a partir de sucessivas mudanças
> fônicas do vocábulo ‘olhai’. Amaral ([1920]1976:190) assim registra
> tal processo:

"Uai: estudo de uma interjeição do português brasileiro", Hadinei Ribeiro Batista (2013).

Para responder sua pergunta, ela não tem resposta.

A conclusão do investigador é de que a origem da palavra UAI *provavelmente* está ligada ao "why" ou a uma mutação do verbos olhar (‘olhai’, ‘oiai’, ‘uiai’, ‘uai’) mas ele não conseguiu provar nenhuma das hipóteses de forma clara.

Baseado nisso, acho que dizer que UAI vem disso ou daquilo seria achismo.

Comment: Eu acho que é achismo :-)

Comment: Tive que ver com os meu próprios olhos para acreditar que exite uma tese sobre isso!

Answer (score 0):

Segundo [este link](https://www.significados.com.br/uai/), a origem da expressão `UAI` pode ser atribuída ao período da [Inconfidência mineira](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconfid%C3%AAncia_Mineira), sendo uma sigla para a expressão `União, Amor e Independência`, utilizadas por inconfidentes para identificarem uns aos outros.