# Qual é o significado da palavra "uai"?

Tags: regionalismo, cultura

A palavra O que significa uma pergunta que se faz referente ao linguajar de Cultura mineira região localizada no Brasil

Comment: *Uai*, em regra, é uma interjeição, logo ela pode significar: surpresa, admiração, espanto, susto etc.

Comment: this question already has an answer [**here**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/teria-uai-alguma-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-com-o-ingl%c3%aas-why)

Answer (score 1):

Como já comentado, uma interjeição, que pode ter vários significados. Segue aqui uma definição:

> Uai é uma interjeição utilizada particularmente no estado de Minas
>   Gerais com o significado de dúvida, espanto ou surpresa. É um dos
>   símbolos da linguagem e cultura mineira

E também, sobre a origem:

> A palavra uai tem origem controversa. Uma das versões, atribuída a
>   Sílvio Carneiro e Dorália Galesso , relata que UAI são as iniciais de
>   União, Amor e Independência. UAI seria uma senha (juntamente com as
>   três batidas clássicas da Maçonaria) utilizada pelos integrantes da
>   Inconfidência Mineira (quase exclusivamente composto por maçons) para
>   que a porta do local de encontros secretos fosse aberta. Era uma
>   maneira de se protegerem da polícia portuguesa. A palavra foi
>   popularizada pelos mineiros e faz parte da linguagem corrente.

Fonte: [Significado](https://www.significados.com.br/uai/)